# Python-Deleting duplicate rows Pandas (Specifically)

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

Here, is the [data set](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Irene-123/Data-sets/main/spotify_top200_global.csv) which I'm working on Which looks like this.
[image]

Basically, I want to delete duplicate rows specifically I know the `drop_duplicate` command but I need some help.

Let me show you by sorting the data so that It'll give you a clear understanding.

```
by_streamed=data.sort_values(by='Streams',ascending=False)
by_streamed
```

[image]

So when I get the top 10 streamed songs the duplicates obviously interfere. If you look closely though the **ranks of these songs are different**

I want to remove these type of duplicate rows. Here's my code,

```
data=data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Artist','Title'],keep='first')
```

[image]

But this removes a lot of rows that weren't supposed to be.

There is indeed an issue with `subset` but I can't interpret it. It would be great if you could help me figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But this removes a lot of columns that weren't supposed to be.` Can you explain more in some small data sample with 5 rows?

Comment: do you mean `rows` and not `columns` ?

Comment: So, you want to remove the duplicates based on Artist, and Title, but not on any other columns? "But this removes a lot of columns that weren't supposed to be." This sentence in the question is misleading, cause you are dropping rows not columns.

Comment: I meant rows.. I have changed in the question

Comment: Would you be able to help me please? @ThePyGuy

Comment: Could you give some example rows that weren't supposed to be removed?

Comment: It's in the question itself. With the first code, the original songs are sorted correctly BUT WITH DUPLICATES.    With this code `data=data.drop_duplicates(subset=['Artist','Title'],keep='first')`                                                                                      listings start directly from BTS and the upper ones got removed . If you notice streams of songs in the 2nd image are more than stream number (For eg. BTS) in the 3rd image